# How can I directly give image to monai transforms?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch, numpy-ndarray

```
import os
import numpy as np
import torch 

import torchvision.models as models
import torch.nn as nn

from PIL import Image
import tempfile
from monai.data import PILReader
from monai.transforms import (
    LoadImage, LoadImaged, EnsureChannelFirstd,
    Resized, EnsureTyped, Compose,  
    ToTensord,
    ScaleIntensityd,
    CenterSpatialCropd,
)
from monai.config import print_config
print_config()

test_transforms = Compose(
    [
        LoadImaged(keys=["image1","image2"]),
        EnsureChannelFirstd(keys=["image1","image2"]),
        EnsureTyped(keys=["image1","image2"]),
        ScaleIntensityd(keys=["image1","image2"],minv=0.0, maxv=1.0),
        Resized(
            keys=["image1","image2"],
            spatial_size=(512,512),

        ),
        CenterSpatialCropd(keys=["image1","image2"],
                         roi_size=(448,448), 
                        ),          
        ToTensord(keys=["image1", "image2"]),
    ]
)

def sgmt(r_img, l_img):
    test_Data =[
        {
            "image1": r_img,
            "image2": l_img    
        }
    ]
    img = test_transforms(test_Data[0])
```

In this code, I directly gave images to `test_transforms`
Actually, 'test"transform' received two keys and file paths of images.
But I changed the code to receive image from user without using file path.

Then I got this error "TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not numpy.ndarray"
How can I give image directly without error?